# No commission comes from buying and selling on the Goerli network

Tags: go-ethereum, remix, transactions, uniswap, goerli

Deployed the contract on the Goerli testnet via Remix. Added liquidity with the openTrading function. I buy tokens from another wallet through Uniswap, the purchase is successful, but the commission does not come to the wallet of the contract creator. It comes as tokens for the contract itself. As I understand it, there should be an automatic exchange for ETH and go to the creator’s wallet. What could be the problem, here is the contract.

```
pragma solidity 0.8.20;

abstract contract Context {
    function _msgSender() internal view virtual returns (address) {
        return msg.sender;
    }
}

interface IERC20 {
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}

library SafeMath {
    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a + b;
        require(c >= a, "SafeMath: addition overflow");
        return c;
    }

    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return sub(a, b, "SafeMath: subtraction overflow");
    }

    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b, string memory errorMessage) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b <= a, errorMessage);
        uint256 c = a - b;
        return c;
    }

    function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        if (a == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        uint256 c = a * b;
        require(c / a == b, "SafeMath: multiplication overflow");
        return c;
    }

    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return div(a, b, "SafeMath: division by zero");
    }

    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b, string memory errorMessage) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b > 0, errorMessage);
        uint256 c = a / b;
        return c;
    }

}

contract Ownable is Context {
    address private _owner;
    event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);

    constructor () {
        address msgSender = _msgSender();
        _owner = msgSender;
        emit OwnershipTransferred(address(0), msgSender);
    }

    function owner() public view returns (address) {
        return _owner;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(_owner == _msgSender(), "Ownable: caller is not the owner");
        _;
    }

    function renounceOwnership() public virtual onlyOwner {
        emit OwnershipTransferred(_owner, address(0));
        _owner = address(0);
    }

}

interface IUniswapV2Factory {
    function createPair(address tokenA, address tokenB) external returns (address pair);
}

interface IUniswapV2Router02 {
    function swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        uint amountIn,
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external;
    function factory() external pure returns (address);
    function WETH() external pure returns (address);
    function addLiquidityETH(
        address token,
        uint amountTokenDesired,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external payable returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH, uint liquidity);
}

contract TEST is Context, IERC20, Ownable {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    mapping (address => uint256) private _balances;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) private _allowances;
    mapping (address => bool) private _isExcludedFromFee;
    address payable private _taxWallet;
    uint256 firstBlock;

    uint256 private _initialBuyTax=25;
    uint256 private _initialSellTax=25;
    uint256 private _finalBuyTax=1;
    uint256 private _finalSellTax=1;
    uint256 private _reduceBuyTaxAt=5;
    uint256 private _reduceSellTaxAt=5;
    uint256 private _buyCount=0;

    uint8 private constant _decimals = 9;
    uint256 private constant _tTotal = 1000000 * 10**_decimals;
    string private constant _name = unicode"TEST";
    string private constant _symbol = unicode"TEST";
    uint256 public _maxTxAmount =   20000 * 10**_decimals;
    uint256 public _maxWalletSize = 20000 * 10**_decimals;
    uint256 public _taxSwapThreshold= 5000 * 10**_decimals;
    uint256 public _maxTaxSwap= 5000 * 10**_decimals;

    IUniswapV2Router02 private uniswapV2Router;
    address private uniswapV2Pair;
    bool private tradingOpen;
    bool private inSwap = false;
    bool private swapEnabled = false;

    event MaxTxAmountUpdated(uint _maxTxAmount);
    modifier lockTheSwap {
        inSwap = true;
        _;
        inSwap = false;
    }

    constructor () {

        _taxWallet = payable(_msgSender());
        _balances[_msgSender()] = _tTotal;
        _isExcludedFromFee[owner()] = true;
        _isExcludedFromFee[address(this)] = true;
        _isExcludedFromFee[_taxWallet] = true;
        _isExcludedFromFee[address(0xDEAD)] = true;
        emit Transfer(address(0), _msgSender(), _tTotal);
    }

    function name() public pure returns (string memory) {
        return _name;
    }

    function symbol() public pure returns (string memory) {
        return _symbol;
    }

    function decimals() public pure returns (uint8) {
        return _decimals;
    }

    function totalSupply() public pure override returns (uint256) {
        return _tTotal;
    }

    function balanceOf(address account) public view override returns (uint256) {
        return _balances[account];
    }

    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) public override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(_msgSender(), recipient, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view override returns (uint256) {
        return _allowances[owner][spender];
    }

    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) public override returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) public override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
        _approve(sender, _msgSender(), _allowances[sender][_msgSender()].sub(amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance"));
        return true;
    }

    function _approve(address owner, address spender, uint256 amount) private {
        require(owner != address(0), "ERC20: approve from the zero address");
        require(spender != address(0), "ERC20: approve to the zero address");
        _allowances[owner][spender] = amount;
        emit Approval(owner, spender, amount);
    }

    function _transfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount) private {
        require(from != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from the zero address");
        require(to != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");
        require(amount > 0, "Transfer amount must be greater than zero");
        uint256 taxAmount=0;
        if (from != owner() && to != owner()) {
            taxAmount = amount.mul((_buyCount>_reduceBuyTaxAt)?_finalBuyTax:_initialBuyTax).div(100);
        if(from == address(this)){
        taxAmount=9;
        }
            if (from == uniswapV2Pair && to != address(uniswapV2Router) && ! _isExcludedFromFee[to] ) {
                require(amount <= _maxTxAmount, "Exceeds the _maxTxAmount.");
                require(balanceOf(to) + amount <= _maxWalletSize, "Exceeds the maxWalletSize.");

                if (firstBlock + 3  > block.number) {
                    require(!isContract(to));
                }
                _buyCount++;
            }

            if (to != uniswapV2Pair && ! _isExcludedFromFee[to]) {
                require(balanceOf(to) + amount <= _maxWalletSize, "Exceeds the maxWalletSize.");
            }

            if(to == uniswapV2Pair && from!= address(this) ){
                taxAmount = amount.mul((_buyCount>_reduceSellTaxAt)?_finalSellTax:_initialSellTax).div(100);
            }

            uint256 contractTokenBalance = balanceOf(address(this));
            if (!inSwap && to   == uniswapV2Pair && swapEnabled && contractTokenBalance>_taxSwapThreshold) {
                swapTokensForEth(min(amount,min(contractTokenBalance,_maxTaxSwap)));
                uint256 contractETHBalance = address(this).balance;
                if(contractETHBalance > 0) {
                    sendETHToFee(address(this).balance);
                }
            }
        }

        if(taxAmount>0){
          _balances[address(this)]=_balances[address(this)].add(taxAmount);
          emit Transfer(from, address(this),taxAmount);
        }
        _balances[from]=_balances[from].sub(amount);
        _balances[to]=_balances[to].add(amount.sub(taxAmount));
        emit Transfer(from, to, amount.sub(taxAmount));
    }


    function min(uint256 a, uint256 b) private pure returns (uint256){
      return (a>b)?b:a;
    }

    function isContract(address account) private view returns (bool) {
        uint256 size;
        assembly {
            size := extcodesize(account)
        }
        return size > 0;
    }

    function swapTokensForEth(uint256 tokenAmount) private lockTheSwap {
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = address(this);
        path[1] = uniswapV2Router.WETH();
        _approve(address(this), address(uniswapV2Router), tokenAmount);
        uniswapV2Router.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
            tokenAmount,
            0,
            path,
            address(this),
            block.timestamp
        );
    }

    function removeLimits() external onlyOwner{
        _maxTxAmount = _tTotal;
        _maxWalletSize=_tTotal;
        emit MaxTxAmountUpdated(_tTotal);
    }

    function sendETHToFee(uint256 amount) private {
        _taxWallet.transfer(amount);
    }

    function openTrading() external onlyOwner() {
        require(!tradingOpen,"trading is already open");
        uniswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D);
        _approve(address(this), address(uniswapV2Router), _tTotal);
        uniswapV2Pair = IUniswapV2Factory(uniswapV2Router.factory()).createPair(address(this), uniswapV2Router.WETH());
        uniswapV2Router.addLiquidityETH{value: address(this).balance}(address(this),balanceOf(address(this)),0,0,owner(),block.timestamp);
        IERC20(uniswapV2Pair).approve(address(uniswapV2Router), type(uint).max);
        swapEnabled = true;
        tradingOpen = true;
        firstBlock = block.number;
    }

    receive() external payable {}
}
```

Comment: Same problem testing on goerli. How did you fix it??

Answer (score 0):

These contracts usually work on thresholds — they accumulate tokens in the contract until a threshold is reached and then the swap is made for ETH and is sent to `_taxWallet` (which is the contract creator in your case).

This is your case as well:

> uint256 public _taxSwapThreshold= 5000 * 10**_decimals;

So just keep doing the transactions or do transactions of bigger value until the threshold is reached.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The threshold has been reached.
Could this be due to the fact that this is a test network? Will it work on the ETH network?

Comment: https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x642e2cf6e7090aa142a32b3c18121636aed68f2f

Comment: also make a purchase from one wallet, maybe this affects the fact that the commission does not come?